# Can a Dragonborn bard use a two handed greataxe as a weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, bard, dragonborn

If so the greataxe is a axe and a electric guitar if you was wondering

Comment: Your question is getting a few downvotes, but no one has said why yet. Your question can be quickly researched using only the Player's Handbook. All weapons have either _simple_ or _martial_ and all classes detail what weapons they give your character proficiency with (whether it's all simple, all martial, or a mixture of specific weapons). Sometimes a subclass or player race will give you additional proficiencies with weapons, and that will be found in their description. I would suggest looking through the PHB before making a new topic here.

Answer (score 12):

### By default, not with proficiency

The Bard's Weapon Proficiencies are (p. 52, *PHB*):

> **Weapons**: Simple weapons, hand crossbows, longswords, rapiers, shortswords

A greataxe (p. 149, *PHB*) is a Martial Melee Weapon, not a simple weapon. Dragonborn does not have any racial trait that would give proficiency with a greataxe.

Bards have no rule that they can use musical instruments as weapons, so that this greataxe also is a musical instrument does not matter.

You still can use it, but you cannot add your proficiency bonus to attacks. (p. 146 *PHB*):

> Proficiency with a weapon allows you to add your proficiency bonus to the attack roll for any attack you make with that weapon. If you make an attack roll using a weapon with which you lack proficiency, you do not add your proficiency bonus to the attack roll.

#### Some ways to gain proficiency

If you have not yet picked your College, the simplest way might be to choose the College of Valor subclass. It gains bonus proficiencies at 3rd level that will give the bard access to martial weapons:

> When you join the College of Valor at 3rd level, you gain proficiency with medium armor, shields, and **martial weapons**.

Such a bard could use a greataxe with proficiency, because it is a martial melee weapon. There also is a feat, Weapon Master, that would allow you to gain proficiency in 4 weapons of your choice but is [generally a weak choice](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/177720/75095) for your ability score increase.

Comment: You might mention the weapon master feat as a way to get it, but if you do, you should also note that it is a colossal waste of a feat. But if they did this, and happened to be college of swords, they could use the greataxe as a focus.

Answer (score 1):

## Yes, with flavor

Since [flavor is free](https://tabletopbuilds.com/flavor-is-free/), you can simply chat with your DM about your concept (guitar that is also an axe for a bard) and then flavor it as an axe but use stats for a weapon that you are actually proficient with, like a longsword. That takes care of the proficiency issue, but we are still creating a dual use guitar/weapon, which is pretty unrealistic. Most guitars get used as a weapon once. But, depending on your game, that may be just fine. **Check with your DM**